# Autofilling City and State from Zip codes in Access 2016

Tags: forms, ms-access, autocomplete, autofill, auto-populate

I am truly a Novice Access user, and am way over my head.  Have been working with Access for the past two months and really just getting my feet wet.  I do a ton of data entry and have relied on Microsoft Excel and a very basic SQL server Query for all of my work.  Trying to upgrade with an Access form to expedite my work.

So I have my main table called Client1 where I enter all of my clients data as I get it from them.  This includes their customers: First_Name, Last_Name, Address, Zip, City, State, County, Date_Of_Signup a few other facts about them as a customer.

I built a form where I can enter all of this information and it fills into the form - But I would like to auto-fill City, State and County based on the zip code I enter into the form.  The past week while banging my head against the wall trying to figure this out I read that I needed another Table in order to pull the data from so I created a Table Named [ZIP] with the fields - Zip, City, County, and State.  I indexed all four fields and made the Zip field my Primary Key since there are no duplicates. I have a One-to-Many Relationship between the ZIP.Zip (1) and Client1.Zip_Codes(Many).

I have tried Lookup Wizard and Combo boxes but I am obviously doing something wrong because all I get is the list of all 3,000 cities without any filtering. I have tried Dlookup without any luck as well.  Every article I have found says it is soo easy, but I am completely lost!!!

Thank you for any and all tips or suggestions.

Mike M

Comment: I forgot to mention my form is titled [ClientData] so I am really trying to have Access find [Zip].[City] Where [ClientData]![Zip] = [Zip].[Zip] to populate [ClientData]![City]

Comment: How about sharing some code? Even the DlookUp.